# JSF Navigation Rule doesn't evaluate security settings in web.xml when rendering a new view unless sending a faces redirect

Tags: java, security, jsf-2

When adding a security rule to the web.xml, as such:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Resource Name</web-resource-name>
      <description>Desc</description>
      <url-pattern>/edit.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>editorRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

Also, assume there is another view called **originalPage.xhtml** that has no access restrictions and that has an action listener that will cause a navigation to **edit.xhtml**. If this action listener returns a navigation rule to **edit.xhtml** view without a re-direct (where the navigation bar in the browser still shows **originalPage.xhtml**), the security settings will not applied and the user will be able to see the **edit.xhtml** view even without being in the editorRole role. However, when sending a redirect by appending **?faces_redirect=true**, the settings are applied correctly and access is denied. I do understand there are other ways to prevent this scenario from happening (such as checking the access in the action listener method, etc), but I still feel that this is an extra piece of security that is missing.

Is there some standard JSF configuration or extension that handles this case? Is this planned to be part of the future JSF specification? In my opinion, this is a huge security flaw.

The only thing I could find on Google is the following, which I have yet to try:
https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/improving_jsf_security_configuration_with